# Map Firestore Data To Object Array Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am receiving data from Firestore in the current format;

```
[(key: "capacity", value: <__NSArrayM 0x600000bd8030>(
32GB,
64GB,
128GB
)
), (key: "condition", value: <__NSArrayM 0x600000bd8180>(
New,
Used
)
)]
```

Function:

```
query.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        guard let document = snapshot?.documents else { return }
        let flatMap = document.flatMap({ $0.data() })
        print(flatMap)
    }
```

I am trying to map this array of [[String: [String]]] into an array of my object such as;

```
struct Object {
    var key: String
    var value: [String]
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Map method execute a mapping and return an array.
You can think that mapping is an operation to do, in your case you have to transform an element of [String : [String]] in an element of type Object.

Following the map Syntax, you have to apply this transformation only to one element and it will return an array of that elements.

In your case you have just to call the Object init.

```
let document : [String : [String]] = ["Key1" : ["Value1.0", "Value1.1", "Value1.2"]];
let objects : [Object] = document.map { Object(key: $0.key, value: $0.value) }
print(objects)
```